# How can I launch Enemy Within from a shortcut?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Ever since downloading Enemy Within, launching the game via steam shortcut instead takes me to a launcher where I must specify Enemy Within or Enemy Unknown.

Is there a way to skip this middle step and launch Enemy Within directly?

Comment: Not sure how to launch Enemy Within yet, but if you create a shortcut to the XCOMEW.exe and add -FROMLAUNCHER it launches straight into Enemy Unknown.

Answer (score 5):

The .exe file which starts Enemy Within is located at:

"\XEW\Binaries\Win32\XComEW.exe", which is under your XCOM folder. With that said, simply right click, drag and create a shortcut ;)

Comment: Hi Oak, thanks for a succinct answer. Have you tested this? I ask because when I tried this months ago, it did not work. But it may have changed in the mean time.

Comment: I use it actually, for some reason the launcher wasn't working for me and I had to do it manually. Beware that XComEW.exe may be in two different folders, but you have to pick the one under Binaries

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: =) Also worth mentioning that the same can be done for the Enemy Unknown version